# Automatically refreshing some PHP Code inside a Java Script

Tags: javascript, php, refresh

I'm building a small monitoring web page on my Pi to track some power readings from a power meter.

Currently I'm adding some gauges to the setup so it looks all pretty, I'm using canvas-gauges (https://canvas-gauges.com/) to do this.

I have a python script in the background pulling the data from the meter and then saving it to a file every minute, which I am then accessing via PHP to display the data on the web page side. I have the data displaying as text, which auto updates just fine, however the gauge collects the variable on start up and then never changes, see code below:

```
...Some code...

<?php
            $dataFile = "data/Data.txt";
            if (file_exists($dataFile)) {
                chmod($dataFile, 0777);
            } else {
                echo "The file $dataFile does not exist";
            }
            $dataLines = file($dataFile);
            $volts = $dataLines[3];
            ?>

...Some code...

<div id="voltsR" class="voltsR">
                    <?php echo "The Voltage is $volts V";
                    ?>
</div>
<canvas id="voltG">
</canvas>


...Some Code...

        <script type="text/javascript">
            setInterval("reload();",10000); <!-- time in milliseconds -->
            function reload() {
                $("#voltsR").load(location.href+" #voltsR");
                voltGr.update({value: <?php echo $volts ?>});
            }
        </script>
        <script>
        var voltGr = new RadialGauge ({
        renderTo:"voltG",
        width:"150",
        height:"150",
        units:"V",
        title:"Volts",
        minValue:"0",
        maxValue:"300",
        majorTicks:"0,20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200,220,240,260,280,300",
        minorTicks:"2",
        strokeTicks:"false",
        highlights:[
                { "from": 0, "to": 210, "color": "rgba(166, 28, 28, .25)" },
                { "from": 210, "to": 245, "color": "rgba(28, 166, 28, .25)" },
                { "from": 245, "to": 300, "color": "rgba(166, 28, 28, .25)" }
        ],
        colorPlate:"#222",
        colorMajorTicks:"#f5f5f5",
        colorMinorTicks:"#ddd",
        colorTitle:"#fff",
        colorUnits:"#ccc",
        colorNumbers:"#eee",
        colorNeedleStart:"rgba(240, 128, 128, 1)",
        colorNeedleEnd:"rgba(255, 160, 122, .9)",
        valueBox:"true",
        animationRule:"bounce",
        animationDuration:"500",
        fontValue:"Led",
        animatedValue:"true"});
        voltGr.draw();
        voltGr.value = <?php echo $volts ?>;
        </script>
```

**What happens:**
What currently happens is that the text section of the code will update every 10 seconds, and after a minute, it will display the newly pulled $volts data from the text file, ie, the first reading will read as "The Voltage is 241.567 V" and after a minute it will read as: "The Voltage is 240.345 V"

The gauge will read the first reading as 241.567 and display this correctly, however after a minute the value does not change to the new value.

If I right click -> inspect the web page, I can see that the $volts variable has not updated in the Java Script section at the bottom, but it has updated in the div VoltsR.

How would I get both values to update accordingly?

Thanks,

Comment: PHP code runs on the server, once. After the page is loaded in the browser, values echoed by PHP into the HTML document don't change, ever. Until the page is reloaded. So `$("#voltsR").load(location.href+" #voltsR");` will work (since the value is loaded from the server using a fresh HTTP request), but `voltGr.update({value: <?php echo $volts ?>});` won't since the `value` is still the one from when the page was first loaded.

Comment: You need to create a PHP endpoint that sends back just the value, then request that with [`$.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

Comment: Hey @ChrisG, so I created a php file with
`$dataFile = "modPwrData.txt";
if (file_exists($dataFile)) {
  chmod($dataFile, 0777);
} else {
  echo "The file $dataFile does not exist";
}
$dataLines = file($dataFile);
$volts = $dataLines[3];


function getVolts () {
  echo $volts;
}`

Then added 
`voltGr.update({value: $.get("/data/getData.php", function(getVolts){
     alert(getVolts);}`

to the update line for the gauge. I'm definitely doing something wrong here though as I get a blank alert and then the Gauge returns an NaN result

Comment: Since it's a GET request, you can start with troubleshooting the PHP end only; just go to http://localhost/data/getData.php and you should see the number. However looking at your PHP code the issue seems clear: you're not calling the function. Just replace the function with just `echo $volts;` and it should work.

Comment: Hey Chris, apologies for going quiet here, things got a little busy. So I removed all the lines from the getData.php and replaced it simply with
```
$dataFile = "modPwrData.txt";
$dataLines = file($dataFile);
$volts = $dataLines[3];



echo $volts; ```

Browsing to the page (localhost/data/getData.php) returns the value as expected, however the graph returns a value of undefined?
The code in the Interval script to update the graph is
```voltGr.update({value: $.get("/data/getData.php")
   }); ```

Comment: Hey Mike, `$.get()` is async. You need `$.get("/data/getData.php", function (valString) { voltGr.update({ value: parseFloat(valString, 10) }); });`

Comment: Ahhh yess!! The glory of success!

I had managed to get it working using: 

` $.ajax({
     url: "/data/getData.php",
     type: 'GET',
     success: function($volts){
      console.log($volts);
      int = $volts;
     }
    });
    voltGr.update({value: int
   }); `

But there was an issue with int and I would have had to define it earlier, and your way is a lot cleaner. Appreciate the assistance, will post your comment as an answer

Comment: Just for reference, even if you had declared `var int;` outside, that code still wouldn't have worked since again, `$.get()` is async. Which means the order would've been: 1. AJAX requests starts 2. `voltGr.update({value: int });` is called 3. some milliseconds pass 4. the async query finishes and `int = $volts;` runs. The fix is the same as always: move the `update()` call *inside* the success callback (or use async/await)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris G assisted in getting me to where I wanted to be:

I created a separate php file that pulled the data from a file (`/data/getData.php`), then used the `$.get()` command to pull this data every so often and update the graph:

```
setInterval(reload, 10000); // time in milliseconds
function reload() {
  $("#voltsR").load(location.href + " #voltsR");
  $.get("/data/getData.php", function (valString) {
    voltGr.update({ value: parseFloat(valString, 10) });
  });
}
```